# SwiftUI getting SF image inside button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following button and code, but cannot get the SF image to go on top of the button. I'd like it to be on the left but on top of the gradient - how do I achieve this please?

```
         NavigationLink(destination: MyView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts(), people: 2)))
                {
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    Text("2")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(minWidth: 0 maxWidth: 250, alignment: .center)
                        .background(gradient)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(2)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20)
                                .stroke(gradient, lineWidth:15)
                        )
                        .padding(5)
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into overlay

```
Text("2")
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .font(.title)
    .padding()
    .frame(minWidth: 0 maxWidth: 250, alignment: .center)
    .background(gradient)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding(2)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20)
            .stroke(gradient, lineWidth:15)
    )
    .overlay(   // << here !!
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            //.padding(.leading)    // might be needed
    , alignment: .leading)
    .padding(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put it inside an HStack.